# How can I query parent to child with two child values and no other child values?

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I have  one parent "quote__c" and child object "Quote_line_item__c" .I want get the parent id

with query some thing like this

```
select id,(select name from quote_line_item__c where name='123' and name='456') from quote__c
```

I know this is wrong .i need to query like this how i can do it?

I need to get the id which only two child objects '123' and '456' exactly .in case it **has three items'123','456','789' it do not show**.

Comment: Have you tried using `IN` clause? i.e. `SELECT Name FROM quote_line_item__c where name IN requireNameList` ?

Comment: @highfive `IN` will be satisfied when at least 1 matches, this sounds like all items from the `IN` have to be present - and only them. `IN` is just a shortcut to not write `Name = 123 OR Name = 456 OR ...`

Comment: Yes @eyescream got it and agreed. It'll not helpful here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky one! Do you have a rollup summary field that holds count of line items? If you do - this might be one way to do it:

```
SELECT Id
FROM Quote__c
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Quote__c FROM Quote_Line_Item__c WHERE Name = '123')
AND Id IN (SELECT Quote__c FROM Quote_Line_Item__c WHERE Name = '456')
AND Lines_count__c = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using Having ??

```
SELECT Quote__c, Count(Quote__c)  
  FROM Quote_Line_Item__c
 WHERE Name = '123' or Name ='456'
 GROUP By Quote__c
HAVING Count(quote__c) = 2
```

Comment: Interesting one! Might burn a lot of query rows though if "popular" name is used...

Comment: I would expect that it only counts the ones matching the having in SoQL query rows, or am I wrong ?

Comment: In regular SQL HAVING is a "WHERE-like" second pass on the query results, you do have all the rows and aggregations and you filter them out a bit more. It would be best to experiment but I'd assume the rows would be considered already wasted for the purposes of 50K limit.